# Supported events from Azure to QRadar

Tags: azure, qradar

Are the resource logs (which are part of platform logs) from [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure) supported in QRadar or do we need to build a custom parser for each of the resource type in the subscription?

I read the [DSM documentation of QRadar](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/dsm?topic=platform-microsoft-azure-dsm-specifications), and it mentions platform activity logs, but not resource logs. Let’s take an example where we get gateway logs, websocket connection logs, request logs, etc. from our Azure deployment. Are all resource logs supported by QRadar to be taken from event hub and integrate to QRadar (list of supported resource logs by QRadar)?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly you are looking to extend existing parsers to QR without having to implement custom properties.

For this IBM has published the "IBM QRadar Content Extension for Azure":
https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/hub/extension/7a89f51852efa37de0809457ef1006dd

I recommend installing another extension "Microsoft Azure Security Center Connected Assets & Risks Connector" (https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/hub/extension/0dbfab6a22bca7add7a99fa19fdd426f), which allows you to monitor other risk events via ASC and integrate assets that are not yet parsed into the QR.

And probably the best scenario how to solve issue with Azure log data is to run side-by-side QR + Sentinel and use Azure Sentinel and turn on Data Connectors for Azure specific resources. This keeps you up to date with integration, data parsing and current buildin rules. We have this scenario deployed and it is for selected sources (Exchange, Teams, risk signins, etc.) and we monitor them via buildin rules in Sentinel. Subsequently, we integrate them into the QR see. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/azure-sentinel-side-by-side-with-qradar/ba-p/1488333. We finally store the logs in QRadar, but we use Sentinel for Azure-specific rules and then integrate the incidents into QR.

Regards.